# CAPH API widgets in Samsung TV SDK

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I have made a very simple CAPH project which consists of a page that has a 3x3 containing images.
I want to be able to do something when I `focus` on an image.
So far I have read the documentation but I was unable to understand.

What I want to do is just reduce the `opacity` of an image when focused.

**This is the code that needs to be edited:**

```
page1_page.prototype.image_3fzrc_onfocus = function()
{
    //should reduce image opacity but don't know how to reference the image
}
```

Thank you.

**PS:** I used the visual editor

**EDIT:** I did something like this but nothing happens.

```
page1_page.prototype.image_3fzrc_onfocus = function()
{
    imgspring= caph.wui.widget._Component.getWidgetById("image_3fzrc");
    imgspring.setOpacity(0.5);
};
```

Comment: Can you check for errors in console?

Comment: @pjp the console doesnt show any errors :s

Comment: FYI, Although off topic,  you should use `var imgspring`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.caph.focus.activate(function(nearestFocusableFinderProvider, controllerProvider) {

        controllerProvider.onFocused(function(event, originalEvent) {
            $(event.currentTarget).css({
                opacity: 0.5
                });
            });
    }); 
});
```

But if you have more elements than images, you can make a condition like that to do not affect any element focused, just images:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.caph.focus.activate(function(nearestFocusableFinderProvider, controllerProvider) {

            controllerProvider.onFocused(function(event, originalEvent) {
                //CONDITION: Just affect to elements with class 'image'
                if($(event.currentTarget).attr("class")=== 'image'){
                    $(event.currentTarget).css({
                         opacity: 0.5
                       });
                }
                });
        }); 
    });
```